# how do you pass textfield value from viewcontroller to my class sqlite3_bind_text function

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, uitextfield

I have set up all of my dbaccess class and its working great with a hardcoded sql query, however now I am looking to implement a paramatized query, and for this I am trying to use sqlite3_bind_text but I'm abit lost as to how to pass the textfield value that will be in my view controller over to this function in my DBAccess class, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new function to DBAccess class which accepts a variable and then use this variable in you sqlite3 query.

Comment: ahhhh... right I see what you mean I will try this now. thank you.